# Any way to create an "auto" width column structure?

Tags: css, html

I have a site that at its top level, has 4 center columns, all of equal width across a 960 grid pixel stage. If a certain query string is added to the URL, the number of columns (including content inside of course) can shrink down to 1 (never less than 1 never greater than 4).

For example:

> www.site.com

will show all 4 columns. Going to:

> www.site.com?col=3

will the site but without the fourth column altogether. The idea continues on. What I am struggling with, is, in the presence of a query string (managed by PHP) is it possible to allow the other columns to "auto" correct their width to maintain the entire width of the page.

SO:

- IF 4 columns, all columns are 220px with 10px margin on each side.
- IF 3 columns, all columns are 300px with 10px margin on each side
- IF 2 columns, all columns are 460px with 10px margin on each side
- IF 1 column, it is 940px with 10px margin on each side

I want to achieve this but dynamically and hopefully within one general CSS class if possible.

### Update

It seems the consensus answer is to use a liquid based format (which I assumed but since the current project is built was hoping for a possible hack I may have been unaware of).

Comment: you can write both css and html depending on the query string- what seems to be the problem?

Comment: There are a number of ways to do that. E.g. Having a liquid grid based on % instead of px, or having a js served by php which access the element and changes the style. What were you thinking about? And which problem did you find?

Comment: Related to my previous comment: Bootstrap has a liquid grid

Comment: @mastazi - I did not want to load various CSS files but the JS option is a valid one. The current project is already built so I fear "starting" over with bootstrap may be more of headache than it is worth. Was just trying to see if there were any css hacks for single elements I was unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [flexible box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) is the way to go here. See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/boennemann/pen/kejHA) to see it in action.
If you don't want to support IE < 10 you [can just use it (prefixed)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: box; //this property needs prefixes
  width: 960px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  background: red;
}

.box {
  box-flex: 1; //this property needs prefixes
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>  
  <div class="box"></div>  
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>  
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks I'll give it a look. Never ran code basically entirely unsupported by IE but I'll see how it plugs in. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll let you know how it works out.